# BSODs from AMD driver when using Flash or HTML5 in Firefox for Windows only

Tags: firefox, bsod, amd-radeon

I have a r9 290x on my system with Windows 8.1 and Arch Linux installed.

On Windows when watching videos in Firefox (Flash or HTML5), I will often get a BSOD identifying my AMD driver as the culprit. The actual message varies, but is usually one of IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL and SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED and always mentions atikmdag.sys.

There are no issues

- On Firefox on Linux
- After downloading the same videos and playing them in a standalone media player.
- On Chrome (Windows or Linux)
- During general web usage with Firefox
- When playing games, even maxed out with the GPU under load.

I have tried:

- Uninstalling the AMD drivers and reinstalling them.
- Disabling hardware acceleration on Flash
- Updating Flash and the AMD drivers.

None of these have fixed it. My current workaround is to just use Chrome for YouTube and Twitch, but is rather annoying. Does anyone know what's causing this and if there is any way to resolve it?

Comment: try the latest beta driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst14-11-2-BetaWINReleaseNotes.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've tried beta drivers, and upgrading and downgrading the AMD drivers, it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: report the issue at the AMD forums: http://forums.amd.com/game/